# Azure WebApp: cannot modify file even though service is stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my app to an Azure WebApp slot but it seems that the file (Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll) it is trying to update is locked even though I have manually stopped the WebApp. I got the following error while deploying my app.

```
Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.)
```

I tried on both VSTS web deploy task and manual deploy from Visual Studio, it returns me the same error message. I tried restarting the WebApp, setting the COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 0 then 1 too but again, same error. The last resort that I didn't try is delete the WebApp and recreate again.. but i would like to know if there are other suggestions first before I do this desperate measure.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting works better, stop just stops the http listener, restart restarts the running proces

Comment: yeah... i tried restarting a few times... the file is still unaccessible

Comment: Just as a way to debug you can navigate to {yoursite-slot}.scm.azurewebsites.net and use the processes tab to see what has a hold of the DLL. If you have webjobs they might be holding on still.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Resources explorer portal to full stop your web app. In this way, we can delete some locked files via FTP without anything running. For more details about how to full stop your web app, please refer to [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Full-stopping-a-Web-App)

Answer (score 0):

As of time of this writing, if you are using Azure DevOps (VSTS) to deploy your application, you can select "Run From Package" in the "Azure App Service Deploy" task/step - this is available in version 4 of the task, under the "Additional Deployment Options" node.

[image: additional deployment options - run from package]

This deployment option eliminates file locking issues as it provides atomicity, in that the application is pointed to the new zip file rather than deploying a bunch of loose files under wwwroot, some of which may be locked.

It provides you with a number of other benefits that you can read about it if you search and read about the feature.

HTH